# Translate Multidimensional Array in Jquery to HTML

Tags: jquery, html, css

With the code that I've posted I'm trying to move pieces on the board in a particular sequence with click of the buttons below the board.  It will iterate through eight moves and eventually I'll setup a fast forward and rewind button.  I'm having lots of difficulty just getting the first piece to move.
I'm seeing my console messages log and even see the movement through the console but I'm not sure how to append it to the HTML I've written.  Also, the board's responsiveness is a little weird looking with the dimensions in the snippet window.  The board is normal looking in full page view.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   "use strict";
  // var move1 = board[6][3] == board[4][3];
  // var move2 = board[0][6] == board[2][5];
  // var move3 = board[6][2] == board[4][2];
  // var move4 = board[1][4] == board[2][4];
  // var move5 = board[6][6] == board[5][6];
  // var move6 = board[1][3] == board[3][3];
  // var move7 = board[7][5] == board[6][6];
  // var move8 = board[0][5] == board[1][4];
  // var move9 = board[7][6] == board[5][5];








var board = [
  ['R','N','B','Q','K','B','N','R'],
  ['P','P','P','P','P','P','P','P'],
  [' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' '],
  [' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' '],
  [' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' '],
  [' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' '],
  ['p','p','p','p','p','p','p','p'],
  ['r','n','b','q','k','b','n','r'] ];

  var move1 = [
  ['R','N','B','Q','K','B','N','R'],
  ['P','P','P','P','P','P','P','P'],
  [' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' '],
  [' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' '],
  [' ',' ',' ','e1',' ',' ',' ',' '],
  [' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' '],
  ['p','p','p','p1','p','p','p','p'],
  ['r','n','b','q','k','b','n','r'] ];

var move2 = [
['R','N','B','Q','K','B','N1','R'],
['P','P','P','P','P','P','P','P'],
[' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','e2',' ',' '],
[' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' '],
[' ',' ',' ','p',' ',' ',' ',' '],
[' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' '],
['p','p','p',' ','p','p','p','p'],
['r','n','b','q','k','b','n','r'] ];

var move3 = [
['R','N','B','Q','K','B',' ','R'],
['P','P','P','P','P','P','P','P'],
[' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','N',' ',' '],
[' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' '],
[' ',' ',' ','p',' ',' ',' ',' '],
[' ',' ','p',' ',' ',' ',' ',' '],
['p','p',' ',' ','p','p','p','p'],
['r','n','b','q','k','b','n','r'] ];

var move4 = [
['R','N','B','Q','K','B',' ','R'],
['P','P','P','P',' ','P','P','P'],
[' ',' ',' ',' ','P','N',' ',' '],
[' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' '],
[' ',' ',' ','p',' ',' ',' ',' '],
[' ',' ','p',' ',' ',' ',' ',' '],
['p','p',' ',' ','p','p','p','p'],
['r','n','b','q','k','b','n','r'] ];

var move5 = [
['R','N','B','Q','K','B',' ','R'],
['P','P','P','P',' ','P','P','P'],
[' ',' ',' ',' ','P','N',' ',' '],
[' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' '],
[' ',' ',' ','p',' ',' ',' ',' '],
[' ',' ','p',' ',' ',' ','p',' '],
['p','p',' ',' ','p','p',' ','p'],
['r','n','b','q','k','b','n','r'] ];

var move6 = [
['R','N','B','Q','K','B',' ','R'],
['P','P','P',' ',' ','P','P','P'],
[' ',' ',' ',' ','P','N',' ',' '],
[' ',' ',' ','P',' ',' ',' ',' '],
[' ',' ',' ','p',' ',' ',' ',' '],
[' ',' ','p',' ',' ',' ','p',' '],
['p','p',' ',' ','p','p',' ','p'],
['r','n','b','q','k','b','n','r'] ];

var move7 = [
['R','N','B','Q','K','B',' ','R'],
['P','P','P',' ',' ','P','P','P'],
[' ',' ',' ',' ','P','N',' ',' '],
[' ',' ',' ','P',' ',' ',' ',' '],
[' ',' ',' ','p',' ',' ',' ',' '],
[' ',' ','p',' ',' ',' ','p',' '],
['p','p',' ',' ','p','p','b','p'],
['r','n','b','q','k',' ','n','r'] ];

var move8 = [
['R','N','B','Q','K',' ',' ','R'],
['P','P','P',' ','B','P','P','P'],
[' ',' ',' ',' ','P','N',' ',' '],
[' ',' ',' ','P',' ',' ',' ',' '],
[' ',' ',' ','p',' ',' ',' ',' '],
[' ',' ','p',' ',' ',' ','p',' '],
['p','p',' ',' ','p','p','b','p'],
['r','n','b','q','k',' ','n','r'] ];

var move9 = [
['R','N','B','Q','K',' ',' ','R'],
['P','P','P',' ','B','P','P','P'],
[' ',' ',' ',' ','P','N',' ',' '],
[' ',' ',' ','P',' ',' ',' ',' '],
[' ',' ',' ','p',' ',' ',' ',' '],
[' ',' ','p',' ',' ','n','p',' '],
['p','p',' ',' ','p','p','b','p'],
['r','n','b','q','k',' ',' ','r'] ];

var counter = 0
var moves =  [move1, move2, move3, move4, move5, move6, move7, move8, move9]

//lower case letters are white, upper case are black.
//each empty class corresponds with an empty space on the board.
//game pieces are numbered per move.
var p1 = $('.p1');
var r = ('.white-rook')
var n = ('.white-knight')
var b = ('.white-bishop')
var k = ('.white-king;')
var q = ('.white-queen')
var P = ('.black-pawn')
var R = ('.black-rook')
var knight1 = ('.black-knight')
var B = ('.black-bishop')
var K = ('.black-king')
var Q = ('.black-queen')
var e1 = $('.e1');
var e2 = ('.e2')
var e3 = ('.e3')
var e4 = ('.e4')
var e5 = ('.e5')
var e6 = ('.e6')
var e7 = ('.e7')
var e8 = ('.e8')
var e9 = ('.e9')


//I'd like to take the variables above and cycle through each move array with a mouse click.

//This moves the pieces forward one move at a time.
$('.forward').on('click', function() {
    counter++;
    if (counter == 1) {

      console.log("Click click BOOM!");
      move1.join('\n') + '\n\n';
      move1[4][3] = move1[6][3];
      move1[6][3] = ' ';
      console.log(move1.join('\n'));
      move1.join('\n');
      e1.append(p1);
      console.log("Move 1");
    };


  });

});
```

```css
*, *:before, *:after {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box; }

.wrapper {
  margin-left: 23%;
  margin-top: 2%;
  width: 46.54088%;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 0.62893%; }

.square {
  max-width: 1120px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  float: none;
  display: inline-table; }
  .square:after {
    content: " ";
    display: block;
    clear: both; }

.dark {
  float: left;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: #43e8d8;
  font-size: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle; }

.light {
  float: left;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: #fffeb3;
  font-size: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle; }

.forward {
  margin: 0 auto; }

.reverse {
  margin-left: 47%; }

/*# sourceMappingURL=styles.css.map */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/meyer-reset/2.0/reset.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/font/flaticon.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/styles.css">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>CHESS, YO!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="wrapper">
    <!-- <div class="board"> -->
    <div class="square light">R</div>
<div class="square dark">N</div>
<div class="square light">B</div>
<div class="square dark">K</div>
<div class="square light">Q</div>
<div class="square dark">B</div>
<div class="N1 square light">N</div>
<div class="square dark">R</div>
<!-- 2nd -->
<div class="square dark">P</div>
<div class="square light">P</div>
<div class="square dark">P</div>
<div class="square light">P</div>
<div class="square dark">P</div>
<div class="square light">P</div>
<div class="square dark">P</div>
<div class="square light">P</div>
<!-- 3th -->
<div class="square light"></div>
<div class="square dark"></div>
<div class="square light"></div>
<div class="square dark"></div>
<div class="square light"></div>
<div class="square dark"></div>
<div class="e2 square light"></div>
<div class="square dark"></div>
<!-- 4st -->
<div class="square dark"></div>
<div class="square light"></div>
<div class="square dark"></div>
<div class="square light"></div>
<div class="square dark"></div>
<div class="square light"></div>
<div class="square dark"></div>
<div class="square light"></div>
<!-- 5th -->
<div class="square light"></div>
<div class="square dark"></div>
<div class="square light"></div>
<div class="empty1 square dark"></div>
<div class="square light"></div>
<div class="square dark"></div>
<div class="square light"></div>
<div class="square dark"></div>
<!-- 6th -->
<div class="square dark"></div>
<div class="square light"></div>
<div class="square dark"></div>
<div class="square light"></div>
<div class="square dark"></div>
<div class="square light"></div>
<div class="square dark"></div>
<div class="square light"></div>
<!-- 7th -->
<div class="square light"><span class="white-pawn">&#9817;</span></div>
<div class="square dark"><span class="white-pawn">&#9817;</span></div>
<div class="square light"><span class="white-pawn">&#9817;</span></div>
<div class="square dark p1"><span class="white-pawn">&#9817;</span></div>
<div class="square light"><span class="white-pawn">&#9817;</span></div>
<div class="square dark"><span class="white-pawn">&#9817;</span></div>
<div class="square light"><span class="white-pawn">&#9817;</span></div>
<div class="square dark"><span class="white-pawn">&#9817;</span></div>
<!-- 8th -->
<div class="square dark"><span class="white-rook">&#9814;</span></div>
<div class="square light"><span class="white-knight">&#9816;</span></div>
<div class="square dark"><span class="white-bishop">&#9815;</span></div>
<div class="square light"><span class="white-queen">&#9813;</span></div>
<div class="square dark"><span class="white-king">&#9812;</span></div>
<div class="square light"><span class="white-bishop">&#9815;</span></div>
<div class="square dark"><span class="white-knight">&#9816;</span></div>
<div class="square light"><span class="white-rook">&#9814;</span></div>





    </div>

  <!-- </div> -->
    <button class="reverse"><</button>
    <button class="forward">></button>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are making a board with set columns and rows, using a HTML `<table>` with proper rows and cells instead of all the divs is fine, and the perfect tool for the job. Will help with responsiveness too, as your current board messes up when viewed with too small viewport (as you can see in the snippet window). Also if you just want to visually move the pieces, a better idea than changing HTML around would be to switch out the background images of the elements. It's easier to keep track of what is where, because the append element functions can be easily messed up. Then you simply change only the board array and iterate through it with every move, giving every element the background image CSS property corresponding to its value in the array. I mean something like this:

HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>  //times 8, changing only the background class (give them IDs too, like 11 for A1, 12 for A2, 21 for B1)
    </tr> //times 8, as there are 8 rows
</table>
```

JS:

```
function move1() {
board[7][4] = "p1";
board[5][4] = "e1";
}

function redrawBoard() {
for(var i=0;i<8;i++) {
    for(var j=0;j<8;j++) {
        switch(board[i][j]) {
        //this for every piece:
        case "Q":
            document.findElementById(i.toString()+j.toString()).style.background-image="Queen.png";
            break;
        case " ":
            document.findElementById(i.toString()+j.toString()).style.background-image=none;
            break;
    }
}
}
```

So basically all you do is with every move change some of the variables in the board, and then call this function to iterate through it to redraw the board, without even touching the order of HTML nodes. Simple, easy, painless and pretty failproof.

PS: `inline-table` CSS property tells the browser that the element should behave like a `<table>` element that is inline. It does not make it act like table cells or whatever. Finally, you may want to set the table pieces' sizes to something more responsive, so the whole board becomes smaller when viewed in a small viewport (smartphone for example, or an iframe somewhere) instead of going out of view.

Comment: Thanks very much for the reply @Deuxis .  I am about to try this out but wanted to ask one thing.  What exactly do you mean when you commented on assigning ids to the table cells?
**//times 8, changing only the background class (give them IDs too, like 11 for A1, 12 for A2, 21 for B1)**

Comment: <td id="11" class="square dark">&nbsp;</td>
    <td id="12" class="square light">&nbsp;</td>
This is so you can use the findElementById in the way I wrote, that way you synchronise what part of the array you check with which element you mean to change.

Comment: Oh, I just realised that the way I wrote the row and column numbers will be 0-7 instead of 1-8 (because the for loop starts at 0 and stops before 8th loop), so either change that to `for(var i=1;i<=8;i++)` or change the IDs to one lower so A1 will be 00, B1 will be 10, A2 will be 01 etc.

Comment: I'll make the changes as you pointed out here instead of changing all of the ids again.   I also wanted to ask (sorry for the many questions, I'm a JS newb) about the function for move1 that you have there.  Would I need to create a new one for each move and just reference the default array from the variable "board"  or would I somehow reference the different variables that have the 2d arrays with movements already done?  Hope this make sense.

Comment: Yes, your code was doing fixed moves step by step, so the way I changed it you need to make a function for each move that changes the array in the same manner you want the board changed (and don't forget to call `redrawBoard()` after every move). And yes, you reference the array of variable board, and change it. You want a queen in D3, you do `board[4][3] = "Q";` and then when you call `redrawBoard()`, queen appears in D3. The `board` array acts as a representation of the board itself.